# django many-to-many recursive relationship

Tags: python, django

I want to implement a basic social network model in django, i.e., followers and followees

```
class CustomUser(User):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followees',
                                       related_query_name='followee')
```

and above is what I define.I think this will be enough because the manytomany field provide backtrack query. Do I still need to create a followees ManyToMany filed?

And could anybody help write the function how to get the number of followers and followees, as well as followers list and followees list. I'm new to django So I'm confused about the many-to-many field

Comment: Try `user.followers.all()` and `user.followees.all()`.

Comment: user.followers.all() works well but user.followees.all() raised exception that user doesn't have 'followees' attribute.    It's weird because this approach should work in general Many-to-Many field.  I'm not sure if this problem is caused by recursion

Comment: If you want a reverse relation, you need to set [`symmetrical=False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No, you don't have to create a (second) followees ManyToMany field. This is already taken care of by specifying `related_name='followees'`. On a sidenote, there's no need to specify `related_query_name` as its value is set to the value of `related_name` by default.
2. A `ManyToManyField` returns a `RelatedManager` which allows you to do some queries on it similar to a QuerySet. In your case you're interested in the `count()`:

   ```
   custom_user = CustomUser().save()

   # add followers etc..

   followers_count = custom_user.followers.count()
   followees_count = custom_user.followees.count()
   ```

The Django Docs have [some nice examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for ManyToMany Relationships.

Comment: can you please provide a URL to the documentation in which `related_query_name` is set by default to `related_name` when creating a `ManyToManyField `?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name

Answer (score 12):

@olieidel is right, but here is one more REALLY important thing, you shouldn't miss in your example: normally, M2M-relations are symmetrical. It means, that if you set User A as follower of User B, querysets will *also* return User B as follower of User A.

You can avoid such behavior by adding `symmetrical=False` option to the field:

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField(
    to='self', 
    related_name='followees', 
    symmetrical=False
)
```